# Ruby on Rails chat Application not working on Openshift - Private_pub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, faye, private-pub

I'm working on an application in which chat is a module too . I'm using `private_pub` gem for handshake of connections - all things are working fine on production except chat . while on `localhost` , everything including chat is also fine . My application is deployed on **openshift** .My private_pub configuration is like below

```
development:
  server: "http://localhost:9292/faye"
  secret_token: "secret"
test:
  server: "http://localhost:9292/faye"
  secret_token: "secret"
production:
  server: "wss://mydomain.com:8443/faye"
  secret_token:"sdfsdf"
  signature_expiration: 3600 # one hour
```

no faye / private_pub error is appearing - The only error that appears on openshift is

> We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)

Comment: change the server value for production to **wss://mydomain.com:8443/faye/faye**, similarly append **/faye** in **test** and **development** server value.

Comment: @Sahil can you place a reference of document for this

Comment: I had made a sample [discussions app](https://github.com/sahil290791/discussions_app/blob/master/config/private_pub.yml), you can check it's code. I too had the same error which was fixed by appending **/faye** to the server values in production, test and development in the configuration file.

Comment: Ok i'll test it and let you know if it works or not